# JavaFX - Creating a Responsive Layout

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, responsive-design

I am creating a GUI application with the following layout:

In a desktop size, I will have an HBox with an image next to some text. In a mobile view, the Image will be above (or below) the text.

What is the best way to create a responsive design for this layout? I have found that switching the FXML during runtime causes a little lag while expanding and shrinking the window, but I want to keep as much of the layout in the FXML as possible just because it's a better design. Would it be best to load both the HBox and VBox FXML files and do a check on the size at runtime and depending on the size change the HBox to a VBox and add the contents programmatically?

**Update**

To be more specific, I was hoping for something responsive *and* clean. Here is a good example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5T-h2czZ4_4

Answer (score 2):

For the case you describe, you can just use a [`FlowPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html). Here's a version of @HendrikEbbers example, using a `FlowPane`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ResponsiveLayoutDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Label textLabel = new Label("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "
                + "consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod "
                + "tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. "
                + "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation "
                + "ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "
                + "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit "
                + "esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "
                + "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, "
                + "sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. "
                + "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, "
                + "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore "
                + "magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud "
                + "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea "
                + "commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in "
                + "reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu "
                + "fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat "
                + "non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit "
                + "anim id est laborum.");

        textLabel.setWrapText(true);
        textLabel.setPrefWidth(360);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("http://goo.gl/1tEZxQ", 240, Double.MAX_VALUE, true, true));

        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 8, 8, imageView, textLabel);
        flowPane.setRowValignment(VPos.TOP);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(flowPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem in loading the spare FXML file at start-up and then switch between them if necessary. You should even be able to do that on a background thread as long as you don't attach the graph to a live scene. Resources like the image can be shared between the two scene graphs, so you avoid the time to re-load the image.

Comment: Doesn't it seem really expensive to have in memory a desktop layout and a mobile layout, and possibly a tablet layout?

Comment: On the one hand this takes some space but if you want to switch between the layouts on the fly without delay I don't see any other option. On the other hand I doubt that the additional space is really that much if you try to share the more space consuming items like images etc. The few different layout panes do not eat up so much memory.

Comment: Is that how web browsers change layouts based on css?

Answer (score 0):

I created a example that uses a HBox and a VBox and switch them depending on the windows size: http://www.guigarage.com/2015/09/how-to-create-a-responsive-layout-in-javafx/

Answer (score 0):

Create a JavaFX application with an attractive layout that allows the user to enter the information needed for a Book - a Book is a class that has the following member variables:
Book: author, title, format {digital, audio, hardcover, softcover}, price, publishyear

When a book is entered, it is added to an array of books.  Your layout should have a button tell you how many books there are, an element that allows you to enter a number to print that book (starting at 1 - so be smart about that) and a corresponding button that allows you to print that book, and a button that allows you to print information for all books entered.         Project Planner

Learning Outcomes Assessed:
JavaFX layouts
JavaFX Actions
Using JavaFX widgets
Incorporating Classes into JavaFX applications

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).